# how to run PhoneGap app in android simulator and deploy android devices developed using Xcode/Mac

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm unable to add android platform

process i followed and error i got

```
Last login: Tue Feb 11 10:33:11 on ttys000
MAC01:~ charan.pathapati$ ls
Desktop             Movies                Phonegap              hellos                tmp
Documents           Music                 Pictures              mkdir
Downloads           PhoneGapApplications  Public                npm
Library             PhoneGapApps          hello                 soapUI-Tutorials

MAC01:~ charan.pathapati$ cd PhoneGapApps
MAC01:PhoneGapApps charan.pathapati$ sudo npm install -g cordova
Password:
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
.....

/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@3.3.1-0.4.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── semver@2.0.11
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── shelljs@0.1.4
├── plist-with-patches@0.5.1 (xmlbuilder@0.4.3, xmldom@0.1.19)
├── elementtree@0.1.5 (sax@0.3.5)
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.7)
├── xcode@0.6.6 (node-uuid@1.3.3, pegjs@0.6.2)
├── tar@0.1.19 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7, fstream@0.1.25)
├── npmconf@0.1.12 (once@1.3.0, inherits@2.0.1, osenv@0.0.3, ini@1.1.0, mkdirp@0.3.5, nopt@2.1.2, config-chain@1.1.8)
├── plugman@0.19.0 (bplist-parser@0.0.4, nopt@1.0.10, rc@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, tar.gz@0.1.1, glob@3.2.8, npm@1.3.4)
└── request@2.21.0 (json-stringify-safe@4.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, qs@0.6.6, cookie-jar@0.3.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, http-signature@0.9.11, hawk@0.13.1, form-data@0.0.8)

MAC01:PhoneGapApps charan.pathapati$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello" at location "/Users/charan.pathapati/PhoneGapApps/hello"


MAC01:PhoneGapApps charan.pathapati$ cd hello

MAC01:hello charan.pathapati$ cordova platform add ios
Creating ios project...
Preparing ios project

MAC01:hello charan.pathapati$ cordova platform add android
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/charan.pathapati/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/VERSION'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:257:42
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)      
MAC01:hello charan.pathapati$
```

Comment: Did you bother first adding the android platform via the CLI?

Comment: @VicM i tried it this is the response i got "The provided path "/Users/*******/PhoneGapApplications/cardInfo/platforms/android" is not an Android project."

Comment: Did you create the project with command: cordova create? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: @VicM yes this is the response i got  cordova platform add android
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/charan.pathapati/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/VERSION'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:257:42
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch .........

Comment: Follow the steps in the link above from scratch, It is hard to help if you did not provide sufficient background on steps followed and feedback about reading the doc.

Comment: @VicM i have updated question by following the above link please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already installed the android sdk? Also add the sdk to your path.

Follow steps
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Thanks for your help.. it did not gave exact solution for the above error.. so, i uninstalled every thing and started from scratch. and struck up in someplace and above link helped me a lot to add android platform but not able to run in android device. it give an error "An error occurred while emulating/deploying the android project. 
/Users/charan.pathapati/CrossPlatform/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error executing "adb devices": /bin/sh: adb: command not found" what is this error.

Comment: I accepting answer for resolving path issue... i got another issue after that but i'm question got solution tnx

Comment: The above error means you haven't installed the Google Android SDK yet. You can follow this very easy step by step guide:
http://galaxy-note-3.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-android-debug-bridge-adb-utility-windows-pc-0149131/